# Geopy location error (in python)

Tags: python, location, geopy

I have a list of coordinates, for which I use geopy geolocator's function to get the related country. But at certain lines I get the following error:

KeyError: 'country'

My programline is this:

```
cim = location.raw['address']['country']
```

It returns the country related to the coordinates. And the error isn't in the coordinates, because if I cut that line from the file, the error will be the same at the same line. In addition the function works out of the loop right.

Comment: Can you show your code so that the readers can look into it?

Answer (score 0):

It's basically saying that there's no `'country'` key for whichever address you're providing.

Are the coordinates always in countries, or can they be in the sea/ocean? Can the coordinates be on the border of two (or more) countries?

If 'yes' to any of these questions, check how `geopy` handles these exceptions. It's possible that it just throws an error (which is happening in your case).

Comment: Yes, the coordinates are in countries, and when I selected the wrong line, and run the command for that, I got result, it's only wrong in the loop.